# My rest api works with curl,but fails in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest

With curl my rest api works

```
curl -d "id=insertCustomer&customerName=Linoy&email=gopu@gmail.com&city=goa&address=test&country=INDIA"    http://localhost:7275
```

When we try it with ajax, its returning the status code as 200 ok.But no response

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:7275',
    data: JSON.stringify({"id":"insertCustomer","Name":"LINOY","AGE":23}),
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        alert('Stock updated successfully Status: '+textStatus); },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

In Rest server, I have a httpd.conf file which redirect to Api.php which

contains the function insertCustomer

Comment: Can you provide both requests info ? (network tab of your debugger)

Comment: Try to add  `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", dataType: "json",` and remove `JSON.stringify`

Comment: try removing `JSON.stringify()`, leaving the object as is.

Comment: Country INDIA
Email lin@gmai.com
Name LIN
id insertCustomer    This is the request going.I have remove strigify.But not working

Comment: is request being made from same domain, subdomain, protocol and port?

Comment: @charlietfl he's hitting 'localhost' so yes, yes, probably, probably.

Comment: @kasdega that doesn''t mean anything with regard to where request is being made from.. question is in reference to calling page

Comment: @AnoopG as others have suggested the stringify could be your problem...Does the code reach your Api.php?  and if so what parameters/values does it have when it gets there?

Comment: @charlietfl no matter where the calling page is located it will call the 'localhost' on port 7275 - granted there is nothing that says there has to be a listener on that localhost on that port

Comment: @kasdega the point being that if calling page is on another port it is cross domain request

Comment: @charlietfl yep, that's completely possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rest class has been included with the following code :

```
                    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

This worked....:)

Answer (score 1):

because you use JSON.stringify the resulting call (in curl) would look like:

```
curl -d '{"id":"insertCustomer","Name":"LINOY","AGE":23}' http://localhost:7275
```

So if your api really works with json, then the above call should work fine as well.

Based on your working curl call, it looks like the api does not accept json, but rather normal parameters. If that is the case then you need to adjust the ajax request and send a url-encoded parameter string instead:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:7275',
    data: "id=insertCustomer&Name=LINOY&AGE=23",
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        alert('Stock updated successfully Status: '+textStatus); },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

If the api function allows both, you might need to set a different content type in your request (without knowing the Api.php its impossible to know):

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST'
contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
....
```

Just try loosing the "stringify" and it should be fine.

Comment: don't have to create data string manually, can pass object to `data` and jQuery will encode it

Comment: only if it is comprised of key/value pairs - so definitely not when using stringify - because then he is passing a string and not an object

Comment: Thank you sir..In my Api function which is a php(it extends class REST in Rest.inc.php),I am not understanding the content type which need to be set

Comment: If you have email address, I can send it across

Comment: if it was stringified it wouldn't be an object. `data: {id: 'insertCustomer', Name: 'LINOY'}` would work just the same as manually creating string and is generaly far easier to use

Comment: The JSON.stringify() method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON 'STRING'. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: I have removed the stringify method..I tried with giving data: "id=insertCustomer&Name=LINOY&AGE=23"..But it seems not working.If its a problem ajax, it wouldn't return 200 ok status.Right?

Comment: @Niko, you're right. jQuery will automatically create the query string from the object.

Comment: @AnoopG hard to say, if it works with curl the way you state  the ajax should work fine. you can try using get instead of post... also check the debug console of your browser what is actually transmitted

Comment: //THIS IS MY //API.PHP                                                                                                                      // Initiiate Library
 
 $api = new API;
 $api->processApi();

Comment: require_once("Rest.inc.php");
 
 class API extends REST {                                                                               }

Comment: The follwoing code made it to work
                        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

Answer (score 1):

Problem is of 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header that is required to be set in response of api from server side. 
But setting it to 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin : * ' is dangerous rather specify particular domains.